# Atom typescript build `Emit Failed`

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

When I try to compile typescript in Atom using `atom-typescript 12.0` I get `Emit Failed`

In the dev-console I see `Error: Unrecognized JSON command: compileOnSaveEmitFile`

When I compile with `grunt` I get no errors.

I couldn't find the string `compileOnSaveEmitFile` in my project.

Please help.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "../com",
    "compileOnSave": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I found that in `/Users/Elia/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/client/client.js` there is a reference to `compileOnSaveEmitFile`

I tried to comment it out:

```
exports.CommandWithResponse = new Set([
    "compileOnSaveAffectedFileList",
//    "compileOnSaveEmitFile",
    "completionEntryDetails",
    "completions",
    "configure",
    "definition",
    "format",
    "getCodeFixes",
    "getSupportedCodeFixes",
    "occurrences",
    "projectInfo",
    "quickinfo",
    "references",
    "reload",
    "rename",
]);
```

I don't get `Emit Failed` any more but the project doesn't compile, in dev-console I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
    at results.some.result (/Users/Elia/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/main/atom/commands/build.js:26:46)
    at Array.some (native)
    at Promise.all.then.results (/Users/Elia/.atom/packages/atom-typescript/dist/main/atom/commands/build.js:26:25)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to "typescript": "^2.6.2" solve the issue.